# No Mobile Login

Tags: joomla-2.5, login

I'm running two sites, both with the same theme and modules, both Joomla 2.5.22. With the test site mobile devices can log in, with the live site they can't.  When a user enters their username and password and hits login, the page just appears to reload.  Putting in a fake username or incorrect password results in the same thing.  No errors appear.

I've tried jQuery Easy and while that fixed a problem I didn't realize was there, it hasn't solved the login issue. I've tried disabling modules (and clearing the server cache, as well as browser cache) and I just can't track down what the issue is. I can only test with an iPhone and an iPad, both in Safari and Chrome, ios is up-to-date. I have no idea how to progress any further, and I apologize if this is a dumb question.

[pf-sgg.lunarius.net](http://pf-sgg.lunarius.net) is the active site.
[lunarius.net/pf-test](http://lunarius.net/pf-test) is the test site.

Comment: I get the error "Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet". Tested HTC One M7 chrome and default Android browser and with Chrome Dev Tools (iPhone 5 emulator)

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm it returns an error message ("Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet") in Android+Chrome. The only difference I see between both sites is Widgetkit's lightbox (enabled in live site). Try disabling it.

You may also want to test if error persists with default Joomla template (to discard a template issue).

Finally, you should seriously consider at least upgrading to Joomla 2.5.24, and if possible, to Joomla 3.3.3. As it seems to be a new project, I think 3.3.3 would be definitely the best idea (2.5 branch will be eol by the end of the year, and no more official support for it will be given by the Joomla Project).

Comment: Thanks to you both, fl0r and Isidro, for providing the error messages!  I've updated to 2.5.24 on the live site and updated to 3.3.3 on the test site; unfortunately while the backend works just fine on the test site the front-end is completely non-functional. I'm going to have to get all of that up and running before I can even think about upgrading the live site.  Thanks very much, guys!